# warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 8

Tags: netbeans, java-8, warnings

My JDK8 NetBeans project has the following warning. `warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 8`
However, my code is building successfully! Can someone help with why this issue is happening?

Comment: You are using a JDK newer than JDK 8 and risk using classes not present in Java 8, so your code might work in your environment but perhaps not with an actual Java 8 installation. The preferred option when using a newer JDK is `--release 8`, which will ensure that the compiled application is compatible with Java 8.

Answer (score 2):

also note Ant javac task now supports this option.

https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html

"release    Specify the value for the --release switch.
When set and running on JDK 9+ the source and target attributes as well as the bootclasspath will be ignored. Since Ant 1.9.8.
Required? No, ignored when running on JDK 8 or earlier"

For example, can replace source="1.8" and target="1.8"  entries with a single release="8" entry.  Note that release attribute has different values (no prefix "1." used).

Note also that this will fail if Ant 1.9 (or better) isn't available.

This can't be used in IDE-provided build files in the nbproject subdirectory, where build files have an explicit warning not to be edited.

Answer (score 0):

Check that JAVA_HOME isn't set to a newer version than what you set in your NetBeans project. For my case, I had an Ant project using "1.8", but my JAVA_HOME was pointing to Java 11.